# DateFormatter returns nil

Tags: swift, dateformatter

Why does `DateFormatter` return nil? 
I think the string format matches?

```
let dateString = ("01/05/2017")!
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

After executing the code above, the dateObj is nil.

Comment: That simply means that the string does not match the date format. – Apple provides a [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) which links to the  [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) documentation.

Comment: `let dateString = ("01/05/2017")!` looks so ugly. What are you trying to unwrap there? There is no optional value in a regular string.

Comment: change your String from `let dateString = ("01/05/2017")!` to let dateString = "01/05/2017"

Comment: Well, this is embarassing. I just had a typo in my code. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `month` you need to use `MM` because `MMM` is used when you having month in the format like `Jan`,`Feb`,`Mar` and so on. So your `dateFormat` should be `dd/MM/yyyy`.

```
let dateString = "01/05/2017"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

**Note:** No need to set `timeZone` to `TimeZone.current`

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your dateFormat:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

date Formatter should be dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check various date format from given link

[NSDateFormatter](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

For given example you can use  `let formaterStrig = "dd/MM/yyyy"`